# Spring приложение поднятоее в докер-контейнере не видит БД,поднятую на этой же тачке в другом контейнере

Tags: postgresql, spring, docker, spring-boot

> Есть rest api поднятое на тачке. При запуске докер контейнера rest не
> видит бд ,из за того что не видит бд,не может подняться контейнер. как
> разрешить конфликт? Хотя если поднимаю докер с рест локально,то он
> спокойно поднимается и обращается к той самой бд

Comment: Необходимо указать соответствующий путь к бд, учитывая, что она запущена в контейнере.

Comment: @Bakhuss в application.properties указан тот же айпи тачки,на которой поднята бд spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://1.1.1.1.1:5432/db

Comment: Какой тачки? Контейнера с бд?

Comment: @Bakhuss да,контейнер с БД поднят на тачке с ip 1.1.1.1.1(Пример). Этот же ip указан в пропертях приложения  и при поднятии тачки он не видит БД.
Если поднимать Этот же контейнере локально на ПК,то подключение идет.

Comment: У каждого контейнера есть свой ip, его и надо указывать.

Comment: @Bakhuss пробовал,не помогает.

Comment: Dockerfile или docker-compose.yml добавьте.

Comment: @Bakhuss 
1)version: '3'
services:

 postgres:
    image: postgres:11
    container_name: "t_db"
    hostname: t_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=t
      - POSTGRES_USER=t
      - POSTGRES_DB=t_db
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/db
    volumes:
      - /opt/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

2)build_and_start.sh для запуска приложения.
docker build -t api --network host .
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 api

Comment: Нужно больше подробностей. Как запускаешь приложения и БД, и как к БД коннектится приложение. Вангую, что ты обращаешься к БД по DNS-имени (твой postgresql), при этом запускаешь контейнеры в разных сетях, т.е. каждый  отдельно. Из-за этого контейнер с приложением не видит БД.

Comment: @Темкатоже Бд поднята с помощью docker-compose.yml выше скинул .

Comment: А приложении то нет, потому он и не видит её. Размести приложение в тот же docker-compose.yml.

Comment: @Темкатоже а разрешить проблему можно как-то если они в двух разных контейнерах?

Comment: Наверно ты имел ввиду `в двух разных сетях`. Ибо они априори в разных контейнерах. Когда в двух разных, то можно прописать маршрутизации. Однако это требует серьезных админских навыков. Проще запустить контейнер с приложением в сети, которую порождает запуск БД.

Comment: Ещё можно поюзать в приложении сеть хоста. См. https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/, тогда коннект к бд будет как `localhost:5432`